# Nodejs Websocket image upload not working on CentOS

Tags: websocket

I implemented the websocket file upload implementation as described on:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploade-in-node-js--net-25445

It worked great on my Ubuntu VM.  But when I uploaded the code to a CentOS 6 server, images didn't work when they got uploaded.  I then tried uploading a large text file, and it was fine.  I then tried a ZIP, and it still didn't work.  The file on the server and the file being uploaded have exactly the same file size so it appears to work fine.  I can only assume some sort of character encoding issue?  But basically I am really stuck.  Anyone got any ideas?

I'm tempted to try using Ajax to get it working if I haven't made any progress in the next day or 2.

Comment: did you find a solution ? I am having similar problem (only not with image).
on my Ubuntu VPS BrainSocket works great, but on centOS socket is not opened.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I re-implemented the image upload to use POST instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.I had to apply new chain rule for iptables,and allow server to listen on custom port for web sockets..After that,everything works great. I had to make it permanent.